# vagrant-lxc fails to start when run from test-kitchen

Tags: vagrant, lxc, test-kitchen

I'm trying to use LXC to run test-kitchen. When I use following .kitchen.yml

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
platforms:
   - name: ubuntu-12.04
     driver:
       box: precise-lxc
       provider: lxc
```

kitchen-converge fails with following output:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: The `lxc` package does not seem to be installed or is not accessible on the PATH.
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc returned 1]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

I can successfully run `sudo which lxc-create`, I have changed my user to 'NOPASSWD' in /etc/sudoers. If I run `vagrant up` in .kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/default-ubuntu-1204 VM starts normally, I can `vagrant ssh` into it and can see it running with `lxc-ls` on host system.

I have tried to dive into `vagrant-lxc` code and commented out temporarily *ensure_lxc_installed!* call in lib/vagrant-lxc/provider.rb. `kitchen converge` failed with following message:

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.2.1)
-----> Creating <default-ubuntu-1204>...
   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'lxc' provider...
   ==> default: HandleBoxUrl middleware is deprecated. Use HandleBox instead.
   ==> default: This is a bug with the provider. Please contact the creator       
   ==> default: of the provider you use to fix this.
   ==> default: Importing base box 'precise-lxc'...
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
STDOUT: Bringing machine 'default' up with 'lxc' provider...
==> default: HandleBoxUrl middleware is deprecated. Use HandleBox instead.
==> default: This is a bug with the provider. Please contact the creator
==> default: of the provider you use to fix this.
==> default: Importing base box 'precise-lxc'...
STDERR: There was an error executing ["sudo", "rm", "/usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-vagrant-tmp-default-ubuntu-1204_default_1399314523513_48531"]

For more information on the failure, enable detailed logging by setting
the environment variable VAGRANT_LOG to DEBUG.
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc returned 1]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Environment:

- Linux Mint 16, kernel 3.11.0-20
- vagrant 1.5.4
- vagrant-lxc 0.8
- test-kitchen 1.2.1
- lxc 1.0.0~alpha1-0ubuntu14.1
- sudo 1.8.6p3-0ubuntu3.1

Output of `kitchen diagnose --all` https://gist.github.com/AlexeyDemidov/11544964

Comment: I'm not too familiar with test-kitchen or Linux Mint but one thing that you might want to try is to use the alpha version of vagrant-lxc 1.0.0+

Comment: @fgrehm I have installed vagrant-lxc from git 'master' and I have the same result - fails to execute 'sudo which lxc-create'. I also tried to switching between ruby 2.1.1 and 2.0.0 with no success.

Comment: weird, what is probably happening is that the lxc executables are not on the PATH when vagrant-lxc is used. I noticed you created an issue on github, let's continue from there and post back the solution here once we are able to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replaced sudo_wrapper call to 'which lxc-create' in plugin source with simple puts `sudo which lxc-create` and got output telling me that sudo requires tty. Commenting out line 'Defaults requiretty' in /etc/sudoers solved this problem.